# Constructor initializing C# string array with another string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, constructor

Deep and shallow constructor work like below.

```
using System;


namespace StringArrayInitializationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] lsa = { "one", "two", "three" };

            // Shallow copy
            MyClass myObj = new MyClass(lsa);
            myObj.EditFirst();
            Console.WriteLine("First array item in local : " + lsa[0]);
            myObj.CheckFirst();
            // Deep copy
            MyCopyClass mycpyObj = new MyCopyClass(lsa);
            mycpyObj.EditFirst();
            Console.WriteLine("First array item in local : " + lsa[0]);
            mycpyObj.CheckFirst();
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        private string[] sa = null;
        public MyClass(string[] psa)
        {
            sa = psa;
        }
        public void CheckFirst()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First array item in object : " + sa[0]);
        }
        public void EditFirst()
        {
            sa[0] = "zero";
        }
    }
    class MyCopyClass
    {
        private string[] sa = null;
        public MyCopyClass(string[] psa)
        {
            sa = new string[psa.Length];
            for(int i=0; i<psa.Length; i++)
            {
                sa[i] = psa[i];
            }
        }
        public void CheckFirst()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First array item in object : " + sa[0]);
        }
        public void EditFirst()
        {
            sa[0] = "one";
        }
    }
}
```

But the question here is can I get deep constructor with shortcut. 
Some thing look like below which is not syntactically correct.

```
        public MyClass(string[] psa)
        {
            sa = new string[](psa); // Syntax error here
        }
```

What is the second way to initialize string array in deep copy behavior (with small code like above)?

Answer (score 3):

```
sa = psa.ToArray();
```

would do the job. This takes the sequence of values and copies it into another array.

---

*Please note this goes for value-types and (immutable) strings. If you want deep-copies of reference types, you have to find a way to deep copy the reference type first:*

```
// assuming a custom "DeepCopyMethod" exists for your type:
sa = psa.Select(DeepCopyMethod).ToArray();
```

Comment: with using System.Linq;